# I'd like to discuss this Venn Diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm very confused about this question. I would like to check if i'm correct or not.

Question:

*For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be $ D_n = (0, {1 \over n})$, where $(0, {1 \over n})$ represents the open interval which extremes are $0$ and ${1 \over n}$. Define the difference between $D_3 - D_{20}$*

My solution:

[image]

I tried to put the sets in a Venn Diagram to make it clear but sincerely i got even more confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a diagram, then some scattered fractions aren't the way to go. $D_n$ is an **interval**. Draw the interval $D_3$ and the interval $D_{20}$; do you understand what these two sets are individually?

Comment: Hm... i think i can draw a line to represent these intervals. First is 0 -> 0,33 and the second is 0 -> 0,05 correct?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that there is no reason to bring decimals into this.

Comment: Okay, then it is correct that this difference set is ] 1/20, 1/3 [

Comment: You are off by one point in the last.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean @RossMillikan?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, because it contains one fewer point than it should.

Comment: What @T.Bongers said.  There is one point missing from your difference.

Comment: Hm. It got me. In fact 1/20 is in the set, right? So the final answer should be: [ 1/20, 1/3[